# Rails 4 has_many: through include associated models' model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following models

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agents, through: :listing_agents
end

class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listings, through: :listing_agents
  has_many :emails
  has_many :phone_numbers
end
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agent
end

class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agent
end
```

I was wondering what would be the best way to minimize the amount of queries run (given an array of listing_ids) which will return all agents, agent listings, agent phone_numbers and agent emails. Normally I would suffice to just do something like

```
Listing.where(id: listing_ids)
```

If the array of listing_ids gets large enough I run into a major problem with N+1 queries when getting the agent email, phone_number and any other possible :has_many associated models I want to access.

Is this possible with some clever inner joins? Perhaps this would be better asked as a MySQL question.

Comment: I am not sure to understant your question.. why do you want to have many queries for ? lets say you have one listing_id, just get the very listing with `@listing=Listing.find(listing_id)` and then you get all belonging agents like @listing.agents.. you don't need any extra query .. One question: you have a recursive Relationship: agents have_many listings, and listings have_many agents. Is there a reason why agents should not belong_to listings instead ? (Your code may be completely correct but those recursive schemes are not seen often)

Comment: Moreover, do agents have numerous emails or phone numbers ? Or by agents you mean the structure of the real estate agent with numerous people working in it ? In this case I would create an employee model which belongs to agents. And add email and phone number fields to each employee (not a dedicated model)

Comment: @Maxence the question is to MINIMIZE (lessen) the amount of SQL queries run. `has_many: through` is very common because it allows all the relationships to be stored in a single table instead of cluttering up the listing table. Thanks for your interest though. 8)